# How to hide an element as page is scrolled?

Tags: html, css, layout, clip-path

I'm trying to hide an element as I'm scrolling up in the page. I'm using clip-path and position:fixed to try achieve this. [This](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-roentgen-98duo) is what I have so far. The text is hidden as I'm scrolling as intended. Wondering if it would be possible to start clipping it from the top as I'm scrolling vs the bottom as it is working right now.

I want the element to be clipped from the top as I'm scrolling down.

One idea I had was to rotate the text 180 degrees, and then rotate the clipped element back 180 degrees but I'm not too sure if that would work/how to implement it. Since transform creates a containing block I don't know how to get the scrolling to work.

```css
#main-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100vw;
}
#clip-container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100vw;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.5);
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.filler-div {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100px;
}
#text {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="filler-div"></div>
  <div id="main-container">
    <div id="clip-container">
      <div id="text">
        <h1>TEXT GOES HERE</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="filler-div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Learn any of the javascript libraries below

scrollrevealjs.org

scrollmagic.io